# Show numerical keyboard_android

Tags: android, keyboard, show, numerical

I want to show numerical keyboard when edittext is focused.
I tried

```
myEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER)
```

but then it only accepts number as an input and ignores backspace etc.

I just want that numerical keyboard is showed rather than letters

Comment: Have you tried TYPE_CLASS_PHONE ? It adds some symbols (#+.), spaces and backspaces.

Comment: I got exactly what i needed with this, thank you! post it as a question so i can accept it

Comment: Done :) good luck with you app !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use TYPE_CLASS_PHONE, it adds some symbols (#+.), spaces and backspaces.

More infos here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_CLASS_PHONE

Answer (score 1):

Do it in your xml layout

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/myEditText"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:inputType="number" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You do it in two ways.

Do it in your layout

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittex"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>
```

Or in your code.

```
EditText e = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittex);
e.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

or if you want anything like dial keypad which will only show you numbers an dwill me able to take input of Int value.
try in code

```
e.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
```

or in layout

```
android:inputType="phone"
```

Comment: Thank you, that is as well an answer